# Class cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting the following error when calling an object to a jsp page.

```
PatientData cannot be resolved to a type
```

I am using an MVC architecture and have imported both my models and controllers to the jsp page:

```
<%@ page import="website.web.controller.*" %>
<%@ page import="website.web.model.*"%>
```

- Patient is the patient class used to store patient data when the database is read in
- PatientData is a linked list used to store all the Patient when the database is read in
- An object of type PatientData is added as an attribute to the session inside doGet

  `request.getSession().setAttribute("data", patientData);`

The error prompts in this line of the jsp code

```
<%  PatientData savedData = (PatientData)request.getSession().getAttribute("data"); %>
```

The name of the servlet is GetData. This is mapped in the web.xml as follows:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>GetData</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>website.web.GetData</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>GetData</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Pilot_1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: did you forget to import `PatientData` class?

Comment: Please don't include "Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance." in your question. Our style focuses on the question, not on pleasantries.

Comment: what is the package of `PatientData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ether do a fully qualified import

```
<%@ page import="website.web.model.PatientData" %>
```

or use a fully qualified class name in scriptlet code

```
<% website.web.model.PatientData savedData = (website.web.model.PatientData) request.getSession().getAttribute("data"); %>
```

.

Comment: Not sure why importing the classes separately still threw an error. But the second method worked, in terms of using the fully qualified name in scriplet code.